# Scala, SBT, a lower version is selected

Tags: scala, sbt, dependency-management

When I run `evicted`  in the SBT console, I get the following Warning:

```
[warn] There may be incompatibilities among your library dependencies; run 'evicted' to see detailed eviction warnings.
[warn] Found version conflict(s) in library dependencies; some are suspected to be binary incompatible:
[warn]  * com.typesafe:ssl-config-core_2.13:0.3.8 is selected over 0.4.0
[warn]      +- com.typesafe.play:play_2.13:2.7.3 ()               (depends on 0.4.0)
[warn]      +- com.typesafe.akka:akka-stream_2.13:2.5.23 ()       (depends on 0.4.0)
```

What I don't understand is why `0.3.8` is selected, even it is not listed at all.

Also strange when I run `dependencyTree` `com.typesafe:ssl-config-core_2.13` is not even listed.

Comment: I'd try run sbt clean and check. Maybe your other libraries are dependent on it. But definitely search everywhere in your projects configs too. Not an easy thing to resolve though. Had similar issues myself